# Titanium appcelerator module for PDFTouch crashes with null value

Tags: titanium-modules

I have create a module of PDF reader having search facility. I have integrated PDFTouch (http://www.binpress.com/app/demo/app/859) framework for this. When I start the app and open a PDF, so, when executing below lines from PDF module, my app crashes.

```
YLDocument *document = [[[YLDocument alloc] initWithFilePath:path] autorelease];
YLPDFViewController *v = [[YLPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
```

I get error regarding 'v is returned nil', so, app crashes when I try to add this view controller into navigation controller. Can anyone help why I get nil viewcontroller on these 2 lines?

Comment: 'document' and 'v' both are not null and being created successfully. I have problems in rendering Pages of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of [PDFTouch SDK](http://www.binpress.com/c/859/5107?slk). The demo version can only be used for evaluation purposes and should not be used in another product like Titanium modules. The original PDFTouch SDK is also available as a [Titanium module](http://www.binpress.com/c/1162/5107?slk) which you can use in your Appcelerator projects.